# Generate libphp5.so without root privileges

Tags: apache-2.2, php, unix, installation, redhat

I'm trying to get php and apache playing nice together on RedHat 5.  I don't have root access.  So far I've got a custom install of apache2 in a non standard location and I've run:

```
yum install php
```

This has installed PHP but I need `libphp5.so` available to get apache talking to php.

Any suggestions about how I can do this without running `make install` would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: May I ask how you managed to run "yum install php" without root privileges?  If that really has run to completion, it should have installed libphp for you.

Comment: The sysadmin did this for me, however `locate libphp5.so` turns up nothing...

Comment: Could you do an "rpm -ql php" and post the output?  My CentOS 5 (=RHEL5) php package includes the library:
[madhatta@www ~]$ rpm -ql php
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5-zts.so
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
/var/lib/php/session
/var/www/icons/php.gif
[madhatta@www ~]$  (sorry about the formatting)

Comment: I managed to rebuild PHP to a non-root directory using `--prefix=...`. Having even more trouble getting Apache to handle PHP at all but that's a separate problem...!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you've got it working, but I think you're in for a world of pain using a handbuilt PHP.  I strongly suspect you have it installed as part of the php rpm; I would recommend that you use that one unless there's a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autotools makefiles have a DESTDIR variable to install in a different location.

```
make install DESTDIR=/path/to/where/you/want/php
```

should install it where you want.

Comment: Thanks, between this and using `--prefix=...` I got there.